# How do I merge multiple rows of vertices together?

Tags: modeling, vertices

Is there a way to merge multiple rows of vertices together like in the example below?

[image: Not connected]

To looks like this (I manually connected each vertex).
PS: I'm sure there is a better way to model it, but I'm just asking as a hypothetical question which would be good to know.

[image]

Comment: X > Edges Collapse?

Comment: Nope, they all go into a single point as if i merged to center or at last vertix

Comment: Yes only select the central edges with ring select, not the two long edge loops on each side  ;)

Comment: Scale them together then Mesh -> Cleanup -> Merge By Distance

Answer (score 5):

Just to illustrate @moonboots' point

- In Edge Mode <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd> select the edge ring
- <kbd>X</kbd> > Edge Collapse

[image]